# Comment form not working

Tags: comments, errors

I'm developing a custom theme, base _strap, with a html template bought on ThemeForest. All is working well, except comment form. When I click on "submit" I got an error saying the connection is not safe, so no data can be sent.

I customized the form using these $args:

```
$comm = array(
    'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

 'author' =>
   '<div class="one-half">' .
   '<label for="author">' . __( 'Your Name', 'syacht' ) . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .'</label>
         <input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
   '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',

 'email' =>
   '<div class="one-half"><label for="email">' . __( 'Your Email', 'syacht' ) . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .'</label>
         <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
   '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',

 'url' =>
   ''
 )
 ),
'comment_field' => '<div class="full-width"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Your Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></div>',
'class_submit'      => 'button gold large marginauto',
'comment_notes_before' => '<div class="full-width">' .
__( 'Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked with *' ) . ( $req ? $required_text : '' ) .
'</div>',

);
```

and then recalled it like this:

```
comment_form($comm);
```

In localhost it is working, but not online. How can I solve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: From whom do you get the error? From WordPress? From the browser?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it. From the browser.

Comment: It seems like an http/https error. Did you check different browsers? Is it possible to give me the url of your website?

Comment: The website is not open yet. Anyway every browser gives me an error.

Comment: Does your site use SSL/HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, it uses HTTPS

Comment: Probably the browser cannot verify your SSL Certificate